# Working with cookies between jQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, cookies

I save a cookie in PHP:

```
setcookie('name['.time().']','Andres',time()+86400,'/');
```

As you can see, it is not a regular cookie value, because it is an array. That helps me to sort() or ksort() the values later.

The user has also a "clear list" button which calls a javascript function. In it, I use:

```
$.cookie('name',null,{expires:-1,path:'/'});
```

But it doesn't work, because the cookies are probably being saved as:

- name[1234567890]
- name[1254567999]

etc...

**jQuery**: How can I delete all cookies that start with "name"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through all cookies

```
var pairs = document.cookie.split(";");
for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++){
  var pair = pairs[i].split("=");
  if(pair[0].indexOf('name[')==0) $.cookie(pair[0],null,{expires:-1,path:'/'});
}
```

Comment: works great! just a small bug (which I still can't fix). Im receiving this in the pairs value: "name[120]=ari"," name[122]=ari", " name[123]=john", etc. That space character before the cookie name is kind of affecting the .indexOf method. Why is that space there, and how could i get rid of it easily?

Comment: the concept works, but it seems that the jquery cookie plugin can't delete cookies that hold array values :s

Comment: You can delete cookies with pure JS functions, lots of them are on google. If space is in front of every name, just change indexOf()==1, or >-1, but second solution is little less secure (it will also delete cookies with name like 'surname[31]').

Comment: i meant that your solution works in terms of finding the cookies. But after some tests i'm unable to delete cookies that have arrays. For example, this works: $.cookie('some_cookie',null,{expires:-1,path:'/'}); but this does not work: $.cookie('name[122]',null,{expires:-1,path:'/'});

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$.each(document.cookie.split(/; */), function(cookieString)  {
  var splitCookie = cookieString.split('=');
  // name is splitCookie[0], value is splitCookie[1]
  if(splitCookie[0].indexOf('name[')==0)
    $.cookie(splitCookie[0], null, {expires:-1,path:'/'});
});
```